# Find values in Array 1 (more than one column) that are greater than values in Array2 (Single column) along columns

Tags: numpy

Suppose I have a numpy ndarray of shape (2,4) as follows

```
>>> array1 = numpy.random.rand(2,4)

array([[ 0.87791012,  0.84566058,  0.73877908,  0.40377929],
       [ 0.9669688 ,  0.15913901,  0.70374509,  0.95776427]])
```

I have second array of shape (2,) as follows

```
>>> array2 = numpy.random.rand(2)

array([ 0.57126204,  0.67938752])
```

I would like to compare both the arrays along the column dimension to find the elements in array1 that are greater than array2 (elementwise). The desired result is

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

If both have the same dimensions, I can directly use `(array1 > array2).astype(int)`. In case of array1 being a multidimensional array with more than one column, I am using the following method involving a loop

```
results = np.zeros_like(array1)

for each in range(array1.shape[1]):
    results[:,each] = array1[:,each] > array2
```

Is there a more pythonic/numpy way of doing it?

Comment: Use `broadcasting` : `(array1 > array2[:,None]).astype(array1.dtype)`?

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape `array2` to 2d array with shape `(2,1)`, then the comparison should work due to [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
(array1 > array2[:,None]).astype(int)
#array([[1, 1, 1, 0],
#       [1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot